# Rails order array by params handling nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to order an array using params i receive from frontend.
I receive the direction as descending true or false so I do

```
direction = params[:descending] ? :asc : :desc
Item.order(params[:sortBy] => direction )
```

If sortBy is name, i receive name desc, name asc, null desc

When it's null it searches for a null column. How do I handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As order handles the values used to construct the ORDER BY clause, giving you kind of security against malicious input, you could just check the value received in the `sortBy` really is a column in the items table;

```
direction = params[:descending].presence ? :asc : :desc
column = params[:sortBy]
items = Item.all
items = items.order(column => direction) if column.in?(%w[id name etc])
```

Comment: I realized the problem is that I was actually receiving "null". But your security tip has been useful anyway, thanks. So I had to do: if params[:sortBy] != "null" && params[:sortBy].in?(%w[id name])

Comment: Nice, notice if the array in `in?` doesn't include "null", then you don't need the first comparison, as it'll return true only if the value in sortBy is "id" or "name" or whatever that array contains.

Comment: You are right.. It's been a long day I missed that too :) Thanks again